# how to check if array item contain 6 digits in bash

Tags: arrays, bash

i am trying to run a loop that checks if an array item contains a number with exactly six digits, and if it doesn't-print it.

```
while read -a course; do
    size=$[#course[@]]
done < tmp2
for ((j=1; j<=size; j++)); do
     if (( ${course[j]} != [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] )); then
         echo ${course[j]}
     fi
done
```

the while loop inserts a line from tmp2 to an array.

then i wanna use the for to check each element and only printf if it doesn't have a six digit number. tnx in advance!

Comment: `$[#course[@]]`? Perhaps you wanted `${#course[@]}`? But even that doesn't make sense, since it only stores the number of rows in the last line of the file when the loop is done (every invocation of the assignment to `size` for each line of the input file overwrites the value from the line prior).

Comment: ...why are you storing `size` at all? You can just iterate directly over the array.

Comment: BTW, if you only want to read the first line of a file, you don't need a `while` loop at all; `read -a courses <tmp2` will read the first line of the file `tmp2`'s columns into the array `courses`.

Comment: Another point -- bash arrays are zero-indexed. Starting at 1 instead of 0 means you're skipping the first element.

Comment: tnx for the answers. my file contains only one line, that's the one i wanna print. i wanted size to count the numbers of words (=rows) so i will have array size. the while loop will only have 1 itiration since there is only one line

Comment: Why have a `while` loop at all in that case? It means if you *did* have a blank line at the end, your `courses` array and `size` variable would have contents from that line.

Comment: i wanted to skip the first elelmnt since it is always a 6 digit number

Comment: And as I said up-front in my very first comment, `$[#course[@]]` is just wrong as an expansion to get an array's size. (`$[ ]` as a math construct is itself antiquated backwards-compatibility syntax present to support code for shells from the 1970s -- `$(( ))` has been the standard math syntax since POSIX.2 was published in 1991).

Comment: BTW, have you run your code with `bash -x yourscript` to see what it's actually doing at runtime?

Comment: in the code i wrote ${course[j]}. it was a tyoo since i can't copy paste from the code atm.

Comment: ...another thing to do in the future is, when asking questions, be sure to include input that shows the problem; current output; and expected/desired output. See the docs on building a [mcve].

Comment: as you can tell i am very new to bash. what other options do i have, if i have a file with only one line but with random amounts of spaces, to check each words if it contain 6 digits?

Comment: Another immediate problem (beyond the typo) is the use of `(( ))` for the comparison. That's a numeric context; you can't do string comparisons in it. You want `[[ ${course[j]} != [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] ]]` instead, with square brackets instead of parens, for a fnmatch/glob-style operation; `(( foo != bar ))` only works of `foo` and `bar` are both integers (or names of variables that contain integer values).

Comment: yea that was the problem. tnx for all the other tips too!

Comment: I'd still suggest adopting the other changes as well -- there's no point to keeping the other bugs (like the ability to be confused by an extra trailing newline) around, or iterating by index needlessly.

Comment: BTW, you can do `for course in "${courses[@]:1}"` to skip the first course, if you want the prior behavior (of skipping the first item) without needing to index numerically.

Answer (score 5):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^- not /bin/sh

re='^[[:digit:]]{6}$'                    # store our regex in a variable

while read -r -a courses; do             # for each line in the input file
  for course in "${courses[@]}"; do      # ...for each column in the line...
    if ! [[ $course =~ $re ]]; then      # ...if that column doesn't match our regex...
      printf '%s\n' "$course"            # ...then print its contents.
    fi
  done
done <tmp2
```

Comment: first of all tnx. still, i would love some input as to why my code didn't work. i wanna know what i got wrong.

Comment: See comments on the question for that.